# Adding language to title of advice questions

Tags: discussion, titles

There has recently been some confusion with [this advice question](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/36068/smallest-python-script-to-print-even-numbers-0-to-100) where people were posting off topic answers in languages other than python. Even though the question was very clear about wanting python advice (tagged [python](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/python), specified "create a python script" and gave python code as the example to be golfed down), there was still apparent resentment on the part of someone who had been drawn in by the title and then decided to post an answer in perl anyway.

I've edited the question title to include python now. I don't see the misleading title as any justification for posting an answer, but I do see how it will be annoying to click on a question only to find it is not what you were expecting. What should be done about this?

I don't personally see this as a major problem as the tags are clearly visible in the question list even without including the language in the title. So should the approach be to edit question titles to include language where tagged as such, or to maintain that a language tag is more than enough and work on educating answerers who post in off topic languages?

Comment: While it may be a good idea to put the language in the title *for now*, if these questions become more common, it would be unnecessary and unwelcome, IMO. The *only* reason that question was confusing is because they're rare now.

Comment: There is already a precedent for this in the "Tips for golfing in *x*"-style questions

Comment: @DigitalTrauma I'm not sure if you're saying language in the title as well as the tags is a good or bad thing.

Comment: @githubphagocyte I think this is a good thing, in the interests of clarity - at least for now, given that most other questions here are expected to be language-agnostic.